# Best practice for managing multiple websocket connections from one user

Tags: websocket

What is the best practice while user connects to your backend (website) from several devices/tabs/browsers, i saw that you shouldnt give more than one connection to user, but also i saw that you should not immediately close ws connection in case user wants to return to this page, so should i have connection pool for each user when front will close some of this connections because of inactivity and backend will close connections when stops getting pinged, or there are better way to do it?